# find any of the substrings in a string: if found mark that string ok

Tags: c++, string

I have string say `"Dog is a kind of animal"`;

Now if I have to find a string which contains any of these words instead of Dog like Cat, Horse, Tiger, Lion then I have to give status of string OK.

I am fully aware of `string.find` function which matches a single sub string to a string. But in my case I have to check the string with 30 possibilities like cat, horse, lion .... 30 animals .

I have no idea how to proceed with that.

```
string line2 = "horse is a kind of animal" ;
const char* array[] = { "cat", "dog", "horse" };    
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<= sizeof(array); i++)
{  
  size_t loc = line2.find( array[i], 0);  
  if( loc != string::npos)  
  {  
   std::cout <<"true"<<std::endl;   
   break;  
  }// end if

  else  
 {
   cout <<"not found"<< std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: If I understand what you're asking I think you could just create a constant array of the possibilities (cat, horse, etc.) and iterate through it using string.find on each one.

Comment: is there is any other way like  using switch  instead of iterating through array

Comment: Well you could use a switch statement and hardcode in every value but that would make your code much bulkier and messier. Also if you use the array it would be easier to make modifications to.

Comment: You can't switch on textual data - switch only works for integers, enums.

Comment: @user535617 .. U mean something like that which I have tried to show in code

Comment: What's your end purpose for this function? Are you going to need to do this on a massive scale that requires best performance? Are there a lot of keywords to search for and will memory be an issue?

Comment: You should use sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) for the array count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very straight-up way to do it (I'll add alternatives in a monent):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string victim = "horse is a kind of animal" ;
    vector<string> targets;
    targets.push_back("cat");
    targets.push_back("dog");
    targets.push_back("horse");

    string found_target; // set to the target we found, if we found any
    for( vector<string>::const_iterator it = targets.begin(); found_target.empty() && (it != targets.end()); ++it )
    {
        if( victim.find(*it) != string::npos )
            found_target = *it;
    }
    if( !found_target.empty() )
        cout << "Found '" << found_target << "'\n";
    else
        cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

### EDIT

If you have the benefit of a C++0x compiler, you can use a lambda to make the code a little cleaner:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string victim = "horse is a kind of animal" ;
    vector<string> targets;
    targets.push_back("cat");
    targets.push_back("dog");
    targets.push_back("horse");

    vector<string>::const_iterator it_found = find_if(targets.begin(), targets.end(), [&victim](string s) -> bool {
        return( victim.find(s) != string::npos );
    });
    if( it_found != targets.end() )
        cout << "Found '" << *it_found << "'\n";
    else
        cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Comment: hi John, Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt. Just a small glitch is there , when I run your first code it run flawlessly while 2nd code throws an error. could you plz highlight me an issue

Comment: I Got error on vector<string>::const_iterator it_found = find_if(targets.begin(), targets.end(), [&victim](string s) -> bool {
        return( victim.find(s) != string::npos );
    });                                                                    complier complains                                                            /string.cpp:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
../string.cpp:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘s’
../string.cpp:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘bool’

Comment: @samprat:  Sounds like your compiler isn't C++0x-ready.  Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using one of the many available regular expression (eg, [google re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/)) libraries to search for the union of your search terms - eg, `(cat|dog|horse|...)`. This ought to be faster than simply doing a search for each of the substrings, as it need only scan the string once.

Comment: +1 for suggesting REs. I'd like to give you an extra +1 for suggesting a non-backtracking RE engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TR1 Regular Expressions. This simple example uses search with a boolean result. There are other functions that let you iterate through multiple matches or do search-and-replace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line("horse is a kind of animal");
    std::regex rx("cat|dog|horse");

    if (std::regex_search(line.begin(), line.end(), rx))
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "not found\n";
}
```

Comment: HI Blastfurance,  thanks for the response , but i am getting few error like regex_search is not a memeber of std, so wht do u suggest me to do to load it. I am using ubuntu and eclipse with g++ gcc complier

Comment: @samprat: I normally use MSVC on Windows but just tried this in my Ubuntu VM. I get a similar error and after checking Google it appears that the GCC implementation of <regex> isn't finished. Sorry.

Comment: yeah , I guess soo. But still I would say your method is really very nice hopefully in future i can use that. Thanks once again

Comment: @BLASTFURANCE, Dear, I have tried your code using boost lib and I must say it works smooth. It was earlier bit pain to use boost as I havnt  used before , but its worth trying. THANKS anD cHEERS

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors here, for example:

- do you care about white space? e.g. can there be multiple spaces between "dog" and "is"?
- do you care about case?
- what level of performance do you need?

The most flexible approach is to use regular expressions.  Boost has an implementation, as do many popular Operating Systems (e.g. Linux man regexp et al).  Checking for a match against something like "^([A-Z]+)\s+is\s+a\s+kind\s+of\s+animal\s$", where the parenthesised subexpression (the type of animal) can be extracted by a regexp library and then searched for in an array.  You may want to use a string insensitive comparison.  This assumes that the list of supported animals is read from some external source at run-time.  As bdonlan suggests - if it's known in advance, you can hard-code it in the regular expression `(dog|cat|...)`.

You can pre-sort the array and use a binary search: C++'s STL already has algorithms for sorting and searching.  That will be a bit faster than populating a `std::set` with the list of animals, but then you may not care about the speed difference.

Another approach is to scan with C++ streams:

```
std::string what, is, a, kind, of, animal;
char unwanted;
std::istringstream input(" Dog is a kind of animal");

if ((input >> what >> is >> a >> kind >> of >> animal) &&
    !(input >> unwanted) &&
    is == "is" && a == "a" && kind == "kind" && of == "of" && animal == "animal")
{
    // match!
}
```

You can do something similar with sscanf, which requires care to with the pointers and not to read too many characters, but is also more efficient:

```
char what[21];
if (sscanf(candidate, "%.20[A-Za-z] is a kind of animal %c", what, &unwanted) == 1)
    // match...
```

Comment: Problem is at this point , I dnt want to include boost lib. and since I am reading from serial port  above solution is not possible as serial port throws a very long string through read function , and i need to break that string if it satisfy my above problem and put into db else discard that string as junk

Comment: @samprat: if the string doesn't match, do you need to still have it around so you can try to match it against some other pattern?  i.e. can you at least afford to read an entire (newline?) delimited string at a time?

Comment: Hi Tony, Well the string I got after parsing through read function of my program doesnt conatin any line feed or end of line. So if string contains any of the following 30 words then i need to put into db else discard it completely as junk

Comment: @samprat: then you can implement it as a state machine: loop reading a char: if it's not space, add it to a string var, if space or EOF, inspect the string var & make your decisions then clear the var & continue.  Re decisions: keep an enum saying which of the terms you need the var to be... it keeps incrementing to the next state until you know if it's a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my response, it ignores case for bonus points!

Helper to get the size of an array:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline std::size_t sizeof_array(T(&)[N]) {
   return N;
}
```

Code to test for valid string:

```
std::string text = "Dog is a kind of animal";
std::string animals[] = {"dog","cat","lion","giraffe"};    
std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), ::tolower);

bool valid = false;
for(size_t i = 0; !valid && i < sizeof_array(animals); ++i) {
    valid = (text.find(animals[i]) != std::string::npos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use c++ STL,
create a set with your keywords as the elements.

std::set myset;
myset.insert("Dog");
myset.insert("Cat");
...

then extract the candidate token from the line
and check if it exists in the set:

myset.count(token) // 1 if match, 0 if no match

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::any_of`. Explained in comments of below example.

```
//LOAD ALL THE REQUIRED ANIMALS.
std::vector<std::string> animals = { "Cat","Dog","Horse","Donkey" }; 

//STRING TO BE SEARCHED.
std::string toBeSearched{ "Dog is a kind of animal" };

//USE any_of. Make a note of "&" in the lambda capture. The "toBeSearched" variable is accessible inside lambda.
bool found = std::any_of(animals.begin(), animals.end(), [&](auto item)
    {return (toBeSearched.find(item) != std::string::npos); });

//HANDLE BUSINESS
if (found)
{
    //Business
}
```

The `std::any_of`, exits the loop immediately after condition is true.